# Error 424: Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

In the code below, I am trying to delete a record from a reservation list (Res_Data).  The code finds the correct record and deletes it; however, I keep getting the "Error 424: Object Required" message on the Loop Until test and I do not understand why.  I do not get the error message at any other reference to rngFound.

```
Dim rngSearch as Range
Dim rngFound as Range
Dim RecordToDelete as Range
Dim sFirstAddr as String

Set rngSearch = Range("Res_Data")

Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=dtDate, After:=rngSearch.Cells(1, 1))

If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    sFirstAddr = rngFound.Address
    Do
        rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
        If rngSearch.Cells(rngFound.Row, iCageNumCol) = "Y" And rngSearch.Cells(rngFound.Row, BegTime) = sBeginTime Then
            Set RecordToDelete = rngSearch.Rows(rngFound.Row)
            RecordToDelete.Delete (xlShiftUp)
        End If

    Loop Until rngFound.Address = sFirstAddr    'Error 424 occurs here
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't tried stepping through your code in debug mode; friendly tip: this is usually the first thing you should do when you run into a bug like this.

Had you done that, you would have found that `rngFound` is `Nothing` once the `Loop Until` line is reached, and this is what triggers your error.

So, why is it `Nothing` there and not before? Well, because you deleted that range a couple of lines before. Hence it's gone. Can't get its `Address`.